# XSLT: wanting to group similar output values and give them relevant headers

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I'm brand new to XML and XSLT, so any guidance is deeply appreciated. I am unable to resolve my issue through researching on my own.

**The Tools I'm using:** I am using the Enhanced Query Export extension for VSTS. This allows you to write an XML document to export your work items in a format of your desire.

**The Goal:** I'd like my output to group work items by their work item type, and give these grouped work types specific headers. For example:

**FIXES:**
Bugs we've fixed

```
TITLE   TYPE   DESCRIPTION
B1      Bug    B1info
B2      Bug    B2info
B3      Bug    B3info
```

...

**IMPROVEMENTS:**
Improvements we've made to the current features.

```
TITLE   TYPE     DESCRIPTION
I1      Backlog  I1info
I2      Backlog  I2info
I3      Backlog  I3info
```

...

**Current HTML Output Example:**
Here's an image of what my output looks like with my current code.

[image: Here's what my output looks like with my current code.]

**Current Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="workitem" match="//workitem" use="System.WorkItemType" />

  <xsl:template match="//workitem">
  <html>
<body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Description</th>      
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('workitem',System.WorkItemType)">

     <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="System.WorkItemType = 'Bug' ">
              <h1>Fixes</h1>
              <h2>Bugs we've fixed.</h2>
                <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="System.Title"/></td>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType"/></td>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="System.Description"/></td>
               </tr>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="System.WorkItemType = 'Product Backlog Item' ">
              <h1>Improvements</h1>
              <h2>Improvements we've made to existing functionality.</h2>
                <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="System.Title"/></td>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType"/></td>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="System.Description"/></td>
               </tr>
      </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="workitem" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: To complete the necessary [mcve], you should also provide the XML file to your XSLT.

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to implement some form of grouping here. If so, take a good read of http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html that shows you how to do grouping in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, folks, for your comments and suggestions. I looked up Muenchian grouping as suggested by /u/tim-c and this was the solution I was looking for. I am grateful for everyone's hints to help this newbie! The code now works when formatted as follows (I've since added some additional formatting):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="wit" match="//workitem" use="System.WorkItemType" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <div style="width:600px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:40px">

        <span class="title">What's New in</span>
        <img class="logo" src="images/app_name.svg" width="252" height="40" alt="" />

        <div class="body_copy">Unlike traditional dashboards or IT tools, Leading Wisely is a self-service, flexible tool that is not IT dependent, enabling users to set and monitor their choice of measure and alerts themselves.</div>

        <xsl:for-each select="//workitem
              [generate-id() = generate-id(key('wit', System.WorkItemType)[1])]">
          <xsl:sort select="System.WorkItemType" />
          <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" />
          </h1>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('wit', System.WorkItemType)">
            <xsl:sort select="System.Title" />
            <h3>
              <xsl:value-of select="System.Title" />
            </h3>
            <xsl:value-of select="System.Description" />
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
      </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to post as comment but formatting was terrible, so I'll post as an answer.

You could also set up 2 for loops and only process if it matches each of the WorkItemTypes.

As I don't have your XML to work from, ill just put it in sudo code below.

```
Output Bug Header

for each workitem
  if workitem is bug
    output workitem
  end if
end for 

Output backlog Header

for each workitem
  if workitem is backlog
    output workitem
  end if
end for
```