# XSLT : system.description displaying empty

Tags: xslt

I'm new in XSLT, I'm using an enhanced query export extension for Azure DevOps. description code displaying as null value not able to get the value

Following format, I'm using get the reference following link [XSLT: wanting to group similar output values and give them relevant headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128017/xslt-wanting-to-group-similar-output-values-and-give-them-relevant-headers)

XSLT code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="wit" match="//workitem" use="System.WorkItemType" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <div style="width:600px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:40px">

        <span class="title">What's New in</span>
        <img class="logo" src="images/app_name.svg" width="252" height="40" alt="" />


        <xsl:for-each select="//workitem
              [generate-id() = generate-id(key('wit', System.WorkItemType)[1])]">
          <xsl:sort select="System.WorkItemType" />
          <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="System.WorkItemType" />
          </h1>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('wit', System.WorkItemType)">
            <xsl:sort select="System.Title" />
            <h3>
              <xsl:value-of select="System.Title" />
            </h3>
            <xsl:value-of select="System.Description" />
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
      </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

below has the sample Description input for xsl

```
 <p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst style="margin-left:72.0pt;text-indent:-18.0pt;">
 <ul>
  <li>·
  <span style="font-stretch:normal;font-size:7pt;line-height:normal;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;"></span>
  <span lang=EN-IN style="text-indent:-18pt;">Byrestricted user doesn’t&nbsp; enter&nbsp; empty space instead of Password</span></li><li>
  ·<span style="font-stretch:normal;font-size:7pt;line-height:normal;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <span lang=EN-IN style="text-indent:-18pt;">MinimumPassword length &nbsp;6</span>
  </li>

  <li>·<span style="font-stretch:normal;font-size:7pt;line-height:normal;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <span lang=EN-IN style="text-indent:-18pt;">MaximumPassword length &nbsp;14</span>
  </li>
  <li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Password doesn’t same as username&nbsp;</li></ul>
 </p>
```

How to display the description?

Comment: We can't tell why your code isn't working without seeing the XML you are using as input.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm working in azure dev ops querie extension tool. Got information about  only the variables type.not about data. Is it possible can we log all input data in xslt ?? If it possible can you share how to do it will more help full. Thanks in advance